# Call function with same name as input?

Tags: python, string, function

Is there a way in python (without using switch statements or if's and an array) to call a function with the same name as an input. E.g.

```
x=input("string input")

def foo():
    print("foo")
def bar():
    print("bar")
```

if `x` is `"foo"` I want to call `foo()`

Comment: `locals()[x]()` but it's a bad idea

Comment: Additionally to @Elazar, use `raw_input()` which yields always a string.

Comment: a better solution would be to put all your functions inside a dictionary and refer to them by their key: `{'foo': foo, 'bar': bar}`

Answer (score 2):

Doing what you're asking is possible, but not generally a good idea. `eval()` can be used almost trivially for any user to do literally anything to your computer (it executes literally any arbitrary code passed to it). Slicing into the local list of variables using `locals()` has no guarantee not to throw an exception, and has its own security concerns related to arbitrary code execution. The better way to do this is to create a dictionary that maps your functions to strings as options for the user to select...

```
def foo():
    pass
def bar():
    pass
def baz():
    pass

dict_of_functions = {'foo': foo, 'bar': bar, 'baz': baz}

choice = raw_input('select a function') #just input() for python 3.x

chosen_func = dict_of_functions[choice]

chosen_func()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with you requirement is that you are mixing two languages: the language of you program, and the language that the user uses. As mentioned by @Aaron, you can use a dictionary, mapping between these two languages (see there).

The important things is that you can easily change the intended input or the function names - these are separated ("decoupled"). You also know that a malicious user cannot call any other function.

Comment: I removed the example, see @Aaron's answer. Please consider accepting it if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

This is a terrible idea due to the potential security risk. Imagine people can decide whatever function to execute in your computer.

You should always define a boundary on which functions are allowed to be executed. i.e. define a dictionary maps command string to function like `{"cmd": func}` This also encapsulates the command name well, the underlying function can be changed without expose such change to the user

Answer (score 0):

If the function is defined in global scope, you can look it up in the global namespace dictionary, which you can access using the function `globals()`:

```
f = globals().get(x)
if f:
  f()
else:
  print("Function %s not found" % x)
```

Comment: So if you happen to have a global function with nasty side effect, the user can control it.

Comment: Yep. As others have pointed out, this is in general a bad design.